# Using Ethiopian oral law to resolve machloket

Tags: halacha-theory, oral-torah, ethiopian-beta-israel

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50880/1713) and particularly [my comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50880/ethiopians-and-oral-law#comment134415_50880) on the question got me thinking. Assuming those who became the Ethiopian Jews received the oral law exactly the same as the rest of Israel, could we potentially use Ethiopian oral traditions to resolve machlokot that arose later in the Tannaic and Amoraic periods and were recorded in the Talmud? If this is theoretically possible, has it ever been done? If this does not work for some reason, why not?

My reasoning, if it's unclear, is as follows. If some point about a Torah law is undisputed in the Talmud, it seems to me that we would have a high degree of certainty that that point was successfully transmitted through the generations without ambiguity. If Ethiopians had a machloket about that point, we would be relatively confident telling them which side is correct. Is this logic reasonable, and does it work the other way around?

I originally neglected to mention that this question only applies to deoraita commandments, and not derabanans. Obviously machloket in derabanans is not a result of ambiguous transmission from Sinai that Ethiopian Jews could plausibly have more clarity on than the rest of us.

Comment: By resolve machlokes, you mean make a halacha or?

Comment: @rosenjcb I don't understand your question

Comment: It's one thing to use Ethiopian oral torah to resolve a machlokes for the sake of internal understanding of Talmudic literature. And then it's another thing to make a halacha based on what Ethiopians do. I know that some gaon (a rosh yeshiva in babylon) said that a Jew who claimed to be from the lost 10 tribes is apart of halachic discussion, but there are other opinions obviously.

Comment: Why assume they transmitted the law more perfectly than we did?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't make that assumption. But if we have disagreement and they don't have disagreement about that particular point but seem to follow one of the disagreeing positions, maybe we can assume that's what was taught at Sinai.

Comment: @Daniel Why would you think that is indicated...unless you somehow trust their transmission better? My previous comment was charitably designed to make your question sensible. If you are not assuming that then I don't know what you thinking.

Comment: @DoubleAA Because they don't have dispute and we do

Comment: @Daniel So...their lack of dispute indicates that they transmitted the law better? I don't see why. All it indicates to me is that they paskined differently than we did.

Comment: @DoubleAA on undisputed points in Talmud, we assume that they are correctly transmitted, so if the Ethiopians had a machlokes, I think we'd feel pretty confident in telling them what the Talmud says is correct. Why not the other way around?

Comment: How about including your reasoning explicitly in the question? I'm still not sure why you think "on undisputed points in Talmud, we assume that they are correctly transmitted". We just assume that's how we should paskin.

Comment: @DoubleAA will do. Regarding your chiluk, what's the difference? Obviously this question only applies to Torah-level commandments and not derabanans, which is a point I originally neglected to include in the question.

Comment: @Daniel just because the talmud doesn't record a dissenting opinion doesn't mean it didn't exist. why should ethopians only recording one opinion mean ours didn't exist?

Comment: @DoubleAA it shouldn't. I'm talking about the case where we have machloket and they only have a tradition from one side of the argument

Comment: @Daniel we have a sanhadreen whom we must hold by. it is essentially like the supreme court. even though they might be wrong and the ethopian jews can disprove them, that is of no use because there is no sanhadreen now to reissue laws.

Comment: @Daniel "only have a tradition" Did you mean to say "only have a RECORDED tradition"? Why can't that mean that the other opinion was around just not recorded? And then how can you use that as proof of primacy?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob The Gemara was written a few hundred years after the last Sanhedrin, so it could have been forgotten between then and the Chasimas hashas

Comment: @ShmuelBrin yes and no new halochoth were introduced after them.

Answer (score 1):

Note, I'm assuming that Ethiopean Jews are real and kept up their Torah knowledge throughout their exile.

1. The [Rambam](http://torahinmotion.org/discussions-and-blogs/eiruvin-4a-measuring) (he quotes the Introduction to the Mishna) famously said that if there's an argument about something, it's a clear sign it's not a Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai.

   It could be an argument in interpretation or whatnot, but it's not a clear cut Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai. Therefore, their Stam doesn't show anything. It's just that they never saw the other side of the Machlokes.
2. Even if one argues on the above mentioned premise of the Rambam, he also [writes](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam.asp?tdate=12/15/2014&rambamChapters=3) (which is something *pretty much* everyone agrees with, even if there are a few caveats thrown in)

   > These [principles apply regarding] the judgments, decrees, ordinances, and customs which were established after the conclusion of the Talmud. However, all the matters mentioned by the Babylonian Talmud are incumbent on the entire Jewish people to follow. We must compel each and every city and each country to accept all the customs that were put into practice by the Sages of the Talmud, to pass decrees parallelling their decrees, and to observe their ordinances, since all the matters in the Babylonian Talmud were accepted by the entire Jewish people.

   So even if the Gemara was wrong, we still have to follow it. Which is why we don't find the Rashba explicitly arguing on Raba, for example.
3. Even among the Tanayim, there were times when the Mishna had a machlokes and the Tosefta was "Stam". The Halacha doesn't follow the Stam.

   > חלוקת במתני' וסתמא בברייתא מאי א"ל וכי רבי לא שנאה ר' חייא מנין לו

In other words, we assume it was R' Chiya's personal decision, and was not binding on his contemporaries. As we don't know what's the source of the "Stam Ethiopeans" (was it an alternate Mishna or was it a much later decision), we may not be able to follow it.

Comment: "since all the matters in the Babylonian Talmud were accepted by the entire Jewish people." Apparently not. Isn't that the whole premise of the question?

Comment: @shmuel halocho ha lamosha misinai is darabbonon and has been passed by the sanhadreen without a a proper masoro on it. therefore it is say in sarcasm that the law has equal state with other halochoth which do have a masoro. its a halocho as good as if it was given by mosha rabbeinu 3alow ha sholom at sinai. but it is not reall from sinai.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe it was that they couldn't accept it. After all, if they had the chance to deny it, then you'd expect references to Bavli and Yerushalmi arguments in their halachic writings.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob it would be helpful if you could find me an online source of this statement of the Rambam. But can a Sanhedrin unrule (so theoretically if we re-did a Sanhedrin the way the Rambam allows we can decide that a Pri Etz Hadar is an apple?)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin the sanhadreen can do whatever they wish as long as the sanhadreen as sufficient evidence to do so. plus they must be wiser(which in many cases they will be due to new scientific facts and such) and greater in number

Comment: @ShmuelBrin https://www.dropbox.com/lightbox/home/rambam%20pdfs%20copy/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%20-%20Imgur this i from my dropbox enjoy

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1731&st=&pgnum=355&hilite= אפילו דבר שהוא הלכה למשה מסיני מדברי סופרים קרינן ליה ואין שם מן התורה אלא דבר שהוא מפורש בתורה כגון שעטנז וכלאים ושבת ועריות או דבר שאמרו חכמים שהוא מן התורה והן כמו שלשה ארבעה דברים בלבד

Comment: ... even a matter which halakha le-Moshe mi-Sinai is designated 'from the Scribes,' given that nothing is from the Torah unless it is explicit in the torah, such as shatnez, kilayim, shabboth, arayoth or a matter that the Sages have declared to be from the Torah, of which there are only three or four such cases

Comment: i dont know if you have mori qafi7's mt but i found an english translation for you on habad's website. Rav Kapach differs and states that the Rambam altered the text in his later years, and the correct version states, "All three are from the Torah." In explanation, he draws attention to the Rambam's Commentary on the Mishnah (Kiddushin 1:1) and to one of the Rambam's responsa, and on this basis differs with the above principle

Comment: He maintains that whenever the Rambam uses the expression midivrei soferim, he means that the practice is Rabbinic in origin and does not have the status of Torah law. The only practices that are considered to be ordained by the Torah are those explicitly stated in the Torah or mentioned by the Sages as having the status of Torah law. In this context, he explains the Rambam's approach. Originally [as evidenced by the Rambam's statements in Sefer HaMitzvot (Positive Commandment 213)], the Rambam thought that sexual relations are the only kiddushin that are effective according to the Torah.

Comment: For not only the effectiveness of the transfer of money, but also that of the transfer of a legal document is derived by the Sages only through Biblical exegesis. Afterwards, on the basis of certain passages that state that the effectiveness of the transfer of a legal document has the status of a Torah practice, the Rambam changed his opinion and wrote that the transfer of a document is also effective according to the Torah. This opinion is reflected in the Commentary on the Mishnah and the original version of the Mishneh Torah.

Comment: Even later, the Rambam accepted the opinion that the effectiveness of the transfer of money also stems from the Torah itself. This is reflected in Chapter 3, Halachah 20, and the corrected text mentioned above.(See Birkat Avraham, Responsum 44, in which the Rambam's son, Rabbenu Avraham, substantiates Rav Kapach's version of the Mishneh Torah.) :this is in regards to hilchoth ishuts halocho 2 chapter 1

Comment: these are all comments that i left in this thread:http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43635/are-halacha-to-moses-from-sinai-undisputed

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob What about Esrog being the Eitz Hadar? If one lacks an Esrog, can he shake an apple to at least fulfill the DeOraisa mitzva?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin no we must follow what the tannoim ruled in the jamaro until a new sanhadreen comes and changes the halocho. the same applies for 2 day holidays. even though we know for sure what day the holiday is on with the invention of calendars, none the less we must follow this halocho which is considered a minhogh. but you can say is it not a barocho in vain and so on and so forth. yes you can say that and that is the reason for wanted the sanhadreen. however, it is not a barocho in vain as of now because we are bound by the rulings of the latest court

Comment: sorry meant, "you can say it is a barocho lava6olo